# Limit by definition when the sign of the variable is unknown

Tags: calculus, limits

I know that for example if we need to prove by definition ( $\varepsilon - \delta $  ) that:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{x}  = \infty$$

We need to find $\delta$ such that for all $N$ we have: if $0 < x - 0 < \delta \implies f(x) > N$
So we can do:

$$  \frac{1}{x} >N \implies  x < \frac1N $$

Thus choosing $$ \delta = \frac{1}{N}$$

Solves the problem.

But, what I am stuck with, is what do we do when $x$ is unknown, thus flipping (or not) twice the whole inequality making it impossible to make the form of $x< \text{something}$

For example, prove that:

$$ \lim_{x \to (- \frac{\pi}{2})^+} \frac{1}{\cos x} = \infty$$

We do:

$$ \frac{1}{ \cos x} > N \\ \cos(x) < \frac1N \\ \text{Illegal move?} \\ x > \arccos( \frac1N) \\ \implies \delta = \arccos( \frac1N)$$

I know that $\arccos$ is monotonically decreasing thus we flip the inequality, but then we can't get to a point when we have $x< g(N)$ we only have $x > g(N)$

Another related question: what do we do when we don't have a monotonic function? we can't just take the inverse to isolate $x$ and keep the inequality the same can't we?

Answer (score 1):

"We need to find $\delta$ such that for all $N$ ...". No, you need to switch the quantifiers.

For every $N>0$ you need to find $\delta>0$ such that $0<x<\delta$ implies $f(x)>N$.

Giving an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof is, although similar to, not quite the same as solving inequalities.

In your second example, given $N>0$, you need $\delta>0$ such that
$$
-\frac{\pi}{2}<x<-\frac{\pi}{2}+\delta\Rightarrow \frac{1}{\cos(x)}>N
$$

This comes immediately from

- the function $\cos(x)$ is continuous and particularly at $x=-\frac{\pi}{2}$
- $\cos(-\frac{\pi}{2})=0$
- $\cos(x)>0$ on $(-\frac\pi2,0)$